# RecyclerView: Why moving an item to the top renders it outside of visible area?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

When I perform this call in the RecyclerView Adapter, the item is moved to position 0, but it's out of the visible area: `notifyItemMoved(position, 0)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move RecyclerView clicked item to the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54763264/move-recyclerview-clicked-item-to-the-top)

Answer (score 0):

Because you also need to scroll the RecyclerView ‍♀️

This creates a nice animation with Kotlin, rendering the scrolling invisible to the eye, so that moving the item looks natural:

In the Adapter:

Collections.swap(list, position, 0)
notifyItemMoved(position, 0)
// TODO: Callback to the fragment through listener or ViewModel

In the Fragment: recyclerView.layoutManager?.scrollToPosition(0)

Cheers!