# How to show a specific List Item on top of the RecyclerView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am developing a chat application where there are users to select and chat with. Check the picture below-

[image]

As you can see the first user or List Item of the RecyclerView is "Cassie Ventura". But I want to show "Rachel Clark" on top because I chatted with her. (for example) That means I want to know how to put a specific list item on top. How to change the positions of the list items inside the **RecyclerView**?
Whenever I chat with someone, his/her name should be on top and that's what I want to do. But I don't know how to do that. I tried **ScrolltoPosition** but it doesn't put the list item on top. How to do this specific task? Is there any function for it in the **RecyclerView**? Please let me know if you want to see any code snippet. Thank you.

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54763264/move-recyclerview-clicked-item-to-the-top

Comment: This does not perfectly fit your case but it will help for sure

Comment: It is similar to my problem, but unfortunately I'm unable to understand what they are saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are really trying to achieve is sorting the list of your `RecyclerView`.

Create a sorting algorithm (you can implement is with a Comparator) which sorts your list first by `lastContactedDate` descending, and after that by `name` ascending.

```
Collections.sort(chats, new Comparator<Pizza>() {  
    @Override  
    public int compare(Chat o1, Chat o2) {  
        int lastContactedDateCompResult = o1.getLastContactedDate.compareTo(p2.getLastContactedDate);  // you need to check for null here. 
        if (lastContactedDateCompResult != 0) {  
            return lastContactedDateCompResult;  
        }  

        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());  
    }  
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is an ideal solution by having timestamp to every chat and sorting in descending order based on that timestamp.

Comment: I get what you are trying to say but I don't know how to use Comparator and how to sort the data I get from Firebase. Can you help me?

Comment: Your RecyclerView hast a List of Objects which it displays. You just need to sort this list and refresh the RecyclerView.

Comment: I just posted a Comparator. :D